# Can i create as many folders as i want inside my gcs bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a gcs bucket and want organise it on the basis of users. I want to make as many folders as my users. can i create possibly millions of folders under my bucket ? Is there any limit to the number of folders allowed inside a bucket ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a limit on the number of files in Google Cloud Storage ( GCS )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525460/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-files-in-google-cloud-storage-gcs)

Comment: Check the comment from Martin and read the docs. There is no such thing as folders in GCS https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders

Comment: Yes, you can create an almost unlimited number of objects. If you are creating massive stores of data with parallel high-speed access, be aware of **storage hotspots** caused by object names with the same prefix. Brandon's answer has more details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. GCS buckets can have billions or trillions of objects and "folders."

That said, Cloud Storage does not directly support folders as a concept. It allows slashes or other delimiters in object names, and it can list all of the objects that start with a certain prefix (such as `folder/subfolder/sub-sub-folder/`), but the service doesn't really concern itself with folders directly as a concept, although many tool and interfaces (like the cloud console or `gsutil`) do pretend that folders exist as a convenience.

Depending on your use case, you may want to avoid having too many layers of folder. If you plan on doing many thousands of operations per second, Cloud Storage may have a harder time ramping up if your objects all start with the same lengthy prefix (see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#naming-convention for details there).

But yes, you can put an arbitrarily large number of objects and "folders" inside a Cloud Storage bucket. If you're talking about billions/trillions/quadrillions of folders in a single bucket, you may want to reach out to the sales team first (https://cloud.google.com/contact), but it will work.